# Load denied by X-Frame-Options: http://somewebsite.com does not permit framing by https://apps.facebook.com

Tags: facebook, iis-7.5, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-apps

We have made a facebook application with c# facebook SDK and hosted the app on IIS. While loading the app, it works fine with the Chrome browser, but the Firefox gives error-

> "Load denied by X-Frame-Options: http://somewebsite.com does not permit framing by https://apps.facebook.com" error

and IE10 says-

> This content cannot be displayed in a frame 
>   To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame."

We tried setting the X-Frame-Options on IIS to allow apps.facebook.com to run the app in iFrame, but it won't still allow the FF and IE to run the apps under iFrame. We have also added the P3P header as well.

If someone can help us out with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Solved the problem. We had added the X-Frame-Options header at two places and this header can take only one value at a time. This is a known issue for this. However it now has been solved. Thanks. Thanks Shadowfax for making the question look better too !

Comment: Put that as an answer and accept iti as correct answer so this question doesnt remain as open